# Updating Claims Value without logging out and back in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, claims-based-identity, claims

I set `Claim` value after register user.

```
 await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id,new Claim("DeActive", "1"));
```

user only visit special pages. after fill a form i remove this Claim, The user can now access all pages.

```
await _userManager.RemoveClaimAsync(CurrentUser.UserId, new Claim("DeActive", "1"));
```

But the problem is that the user has to log in again to clear the Claim.

How to update Claims value without logout?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your claim will update, after you remove/add it.

The issue ***is HOW LONG does it take***... in your `startupAuth.cs` you have setting that needs to be modified my guess is you used the default its ~30 mins, change that to

> `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)` to `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(75)`

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/HiddenLogin"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {                      
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), // change this as above
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```